# EloquentJavaScript: !Number.isNaN() what is the purpose?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

In Eloquent JavaScript rev.3 (http://eloquentjavascript.net/02_program_structure.html)there is a code snippet:

```
let theNumber = Number(prompt("Pick a number"));
if (!Number.isNaN(theNumber)) {
  console.log("Your number is the square root of " +
              theNumber * theNumber);
}
```

Here is what I understand:

First: create a variable and assign the window.prompt method to it. Use the Number wrapper object to convert the string to a number.

Second: Create a conditional and check if the the variable is NaN (not a number)
If no (the ! operator), log the square root in the console.

What I don't understand is the meaning of !Number.isNaN...
Why is the author doing it that way?

Isn't it enough to just write the condition as:

```
if (!isNaN(theNumber) {...}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: They are not quite equivalent, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN#Examples for the differences.

Comment: To explain the difference.. ->  `Number.isNaN("NaN") === false`   but  `isNaN("NaN") === true`